# Export only specific range of rows in Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I know MySQL but I don't know Access. I have nearly 1 million rows and I want only the rows between 300 000 and 500 000. I mean as seperate file. I don't need the ones before 300 000 and the ones after 500 000. How I'll do it?

The Access is 2013.

Comment: As it stands, this is not a programming question.

Comment: No, it is a programming question. I was expecting an sql delete query.

Comment: If you wanted a delete query why did you ask how to "export" selected rows to a "separate file"...?

Comment: ilhan Please improve and clarify your question. As it stands, it is not a programming question.

Comment: May be this question should be moved to Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a query that selects the rows you want to export and outputs all of the columns in the table. Such a query will look something like this:

[image]

- Close and save the query. Give it a name like "toExport".

**To export the rows to CSV, Excel, etc.**

- Right-click the query name in the object pane (on the left side of the Access window) and choose "Export", then choose the destination (type of file you want to create). The wizard will take you through the process.

**To create a table in another Access database**

- Open the destination database, select the "External Data" tab, and choose "Access" under "Import & Link". Choose the "Import" option, then select the query you created in the source database. Be sure to choose the "As Tables" option under "Import Queries".

[image: Access import options dialog]

Comment: This is a valid solution, but this is not a programming answer and Stackoverflow is a programming site, so are you saying the question does not belong here?

Comment: This exports the query, not the data. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: In MS Access 2013, right clicking will give you a list of possible export opeiotns - Excel, PDF, Word and so on. The data will be exported.

Comment: I have selected Access and it exported the query itself.

Comment: I updated the answer for Access-to-Access transfers.

Comment: @Remou I *could* have posted VBA code, but that seemed silly based on my understanding of the question. If this answer is such a blot on Stack Overflow then perhaps TPTB will migrate it to Super User.

Answer (score 2):

If you can base the range on an ID, the query is simple enough:

```
DELETE
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.ID<300000 Or Table1.ID>500000
```